# Is there a limited number of GroupedFlux<T> created groupBy operator

Tags: java, project-reactor

According to the [document reference](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/snapshot/reference/#_grouping_with_code_flux_groupedflux_t_code) the groupBy operator splits a given Flux into multiple GroupedFlux depending on the keymapper function of the operator.
If I execute the following code with a range of 257 integers, it works correctly bu not with 258

```
    public void groupByTest() {
    Flux.range(1, 258)
            .groupBy(val -> val)
            .concatMap(g -> g.map(val -> val + "test"))
            .doOnNext(System.out::println)
            .blockLast();
}
```

Is that mean that the groupBy operator cannot create more than 257 groups?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in the `groupBy` javadoc:

> The groups need to be drained and consumed downstream for groupBy to work correctly. Notably when the criteria produces a large amount of groups, it can lead to hanging if the groups are not suitably consumed downstream (eg. due to a `flatMap` with a `maxConcurrency` parameter that is set too low).

What that means is that once a group is emitted, `groupBy` needs to get more request for it to make progress. By default, it opens up to 256 groups and then it needs either more request or to detect that a group is complete. And `groupBy` cannot "know" if a group is complete until either:

- A) the group is cancelled (in which case it will recreate a new group if a value with the same key appears later)
- B) the source has been entirely processed (which can only happen if the source is < 256 elements, the default groupBy `prefetch`, or if `groupBy` received `onComplete` signal from the source)

Both the `val -> val` criteria and `concatMap` work against these requirements.

The `groupBy` criteria ultimately generates as many groups as there are values. Here 258 groups, vs a default capacity for `groupBy` to keep track of 256 groups.

> **Note**: If the whole sequence starts less than 256 groups, it would work fine. 
>   *Try setting the criteria to `val -> val % 2` and see that it works. Then try to bump the range to `range(1, 513)` and see how it hangs again*.

The last test was limited to 512 elements due to how `concatMap` works.

`concatMap` is especially bad in our case, because it will only subscribe to the next group and make progress **when the first group has completed**. This clashes with condition B) above, creating a situation where neither `groupBy` nor `concatMap` can make progress.

> **Note**: In the small example with 513, `concatMap` would start consuming group
>   1 and wait for it to complete before it consumes group 2. BUT
>   `groupBy` stops emitting once it has fetched 256 elements for group 1
>   and then waits for downstream to start consuming group 2. As a result,
>   it has just too few data to detect that the group is complete,
>   `concatMap` waits for that completion signal and never subscribes to
>   group 2, hanging the whole thing.
>
> Using a `flatMap` would fix that, because `flatMap` will subscribe to multiple groups concurrently, and 2 groups is no trouble for it: it will consume both groups and make progress.

Comment: Assume there are >256 groups, `prefetch` is not increased and each inner group flux only generates a small number of elements (e.g. `g.buffer(3)`). Is there a way to complete the inner group flux somehow or any other way to let `groupBy` know that group is done? Or alternatively is there a better way to tackle grouped processing (with a lot of groups) in with reactive programming?

Comment: @levantpied there could be a way assuming the last element in each group can be detected: you could then use `takeUntil(Predicate)` or `takeWhile(Predicate)` in order to trigger a cancellation of the group when it is informally complete. cancelling a group closes it from the groupBy perspective

Comment: Great, I think that is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! What about cases where that's not possible (or easy), what's the recommended reactive approach?

Comment: I'd say to explore windowing/buffering solutions instead of groupBy. maybe combine the two approaches (grouping on a window of max n elements)